# Sample ARB Request Update XML

Tags: xml, authorize.net, authorize.net-arb

Can anyone give me a sample xml of ARB Request Update?

I need to update the amount and the subscription name. Thanks.. :)

I already read the ARB XML guide but I am having problem with the syntax when updating an ARB.

Answer (score 1):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The following is the XML sent to successfully create a new subscription.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
  <merchantAuthentication>
    <name>mytestacct</name>
    <transactionKey>112223344</transactionKey>
  </merchantAuthentication>
  <refId>Sample</refId>
  <subscription>
    <name>Sample subscription</name>
    <paymentSchedule>
      <interval>
        <length>1</length>
        <unit>months</unit>
      </interval>
      <startDate>2007-03-15</startDate>
      <totalOccurrences>12</totalOccurrences>
      <trialOccurrences>1</trialOccurrences>
    </paymentSchedule>
    <amount>10.29</amount>
    <trialAmount>0.00</trialAmount>
    <payment>
      <creditCard>
        <cardNumber>4111111111111111</cardNumber>
        <expirationDate>2008-08</expirationDate>
      </creditCard>
    </payment>
    <billTo>
      <firstName>John</firstName>
      <lastName>Smith</lastName>
    </billTo>
  </subscription>
</ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ARBUpdateSubscriptionRequest xmlns=\"AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd\">  
    <merchantAuthentication>  
        <name> LoginId </name>  
        <transactionKey> Transaction Key </transactionKey>  
    </merchantAuthentication>  
    <subscriptionId> Subscription Id </subscriptionId>  
    <subscription>  
        <name> Subscription Name </name>  
        <amount> Amount </amount>
    </subscription>                 
</ARBUpdateSubscriptionRequest>
```